# Sync Invoke Component in ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to Invoke a Sync component using ASP.NET Core 1.0 so I have:

```
public class ExampleViewComponent : ViewComponent {

  public IViewComponentResult InvokeAsync() {
    ExampleModel model = new ExampleModel(2);
    return View(model);
  }

}
```

And trying to invoke it as follows:

@Component.InvokeAsync("Example")

But I then get the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Method 'InvokeAsync' of view component 'MVCApp.Components.ExampleViewComponent' should be declared to return Task<T>.
```

I am using InvokeAsync because Invoke was removed in 1.0.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: Method 'InvokeAsync' of view component 'MVCApp.Components.ExampleViewComponent' should be declared to return Task<T>.

Read the message and follow the instructions...

```
public class ExampleViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync() {
        ExampleModel model = new ExampleModel(2);

        // returns a finished task
        return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View(model));
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I wrong or you missing the async in the method return? And then you need to add an await in the method code which does not have any async operation. That is the problem.

Comment: No, you don't need `async`. Only if you really perform an async operation and use `await`. You can return a finished task though. I'll update it

Comment: I was using await Task.Delay(0); as a workaround but your solution is better. Just marked as answer.